# How to set custom widget on QMainWindow in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, custom-widgets

I am trying to have a custom widget displayed on pyQT main window but for some reason, I am getting two windows instead of the custom widget defined in the function years i.e. checkable combo box displayed in Dialog_01 (main window). Below is my code. Appreciate if someone has any direction or documentation I can look in.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMenu, QVBoxLayout, QSizePolicy, QMessageBox, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
class CheckableComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    closedPopup = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CheckableComboBox, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setView(QtWidgets.QListView(self))
        self.view().pressed.connect(self.handleItemPressed)
        self.setModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self))

        firstItem = QtGui.QStandardItem("Select Years")
        firstItem.setBackground(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(200, 200, 200)))
        firstItem.setSelectable(False)
        self.model().appendRow(firstItem)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    def handleItemPressed(self, index):
        item = self.model().itemFromIndex(index)
        if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        else:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)

    def checkedItems(self):
        l = []
        for i in range(self.model().rowCount()):
            it = self.model().item(i)
            if it.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                l.append(it.text())
        return l

    def hidePopup(self):
        self.closedPopup.emit()
        super(CheckableComboBox, self).hidePopup()
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: self.setCurrentIndex(0))
class Dialog_01(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "Title"  
        self.top = 100        
        self.left = 100        
        self.width = 800      
        self.height = 500
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)
        self.years()
        self.location()
        self.MaxYears()

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.listWidget = self.comboBoxv
        self.layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.listWidget.show()
    def years(self):
        label0 = QLabel('Years', self)
        label0.move(50,50)
        label0.setGeometry(50,50,500,20)

        years = ["2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022"]
        self.comboBoxv = CheckableComboBox()
        for i, area in enumerate(years):
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(area)
            item.setCheckable(True)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.comboBoxv.model().appendRow(item)        
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.listWidget = self.comboBoxv
        self.layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.listWidget.move(300, 50)


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_closedPopup(self):
        print(len(self.comboBoxv.checkedItems()))


    def location(self):  
        label1 = QLabel('Location', self)
        label1.move(50,150)
        label1.setGeometry(50,150,500,20)
        comboBox1 = QComboBox(self)
        for i in range(1,15):
            comboBox1.addItem("LOCATION %i" % i)
        comboBox1.move(300, 150)
        self.locationDrop=comboBox1
    def MaxYears(self):
        label2 = QLabel('Maximum Years', self)
        label2.move(50,250)
        label2.setGeometry(50,250,500,20)
        comboBox2 = QComboBox(self)
        for i in range(1, 10):
            comboBox2.addItem(str(i))
        comboBox2.move(300, 250)
        self.maxyearsDrop=comboBox2

if __name__ == '__main__':

    if not QApplication.instance():
        App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        App = QApplication.instance()
    ui = Dialog_01()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())
```

Comment: Your question is clear in the sense that it describes the problem that you get but it is not clear in what you want since I can think of many places to place CheckableComboBox.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to understand that programming is not placing nonsensical code, for example: *what did you try to do with `self.listWidget = self.comboBoxv`?*, as well as the above there are several inconsistencies.

---

On the other hand QMainWindow is a special widget since it already has a layout:

[image]

So you must create a centralwidget where you set the layout.

---

If you are going to use layouts you should no longer use the geometry, move or resize methods since the layout would handle those properties.

---

On the other hand I think you want to make a formula where there is a description and an editor, in that case Qt provides the QFormLayout.

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class CheckableComboBox(QtWidgets.QComboBox):
    closedPopup = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CheckableComboBox, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setView(QtWidgets.QListView(self))
        self.view().pressed.connect(self.handleItemPressed)
        self.setModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self))

        firstItem = QtGui.QStandardItem("Select Years")
        firstItem.setBackground(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(200, 200, 200)))
        firstItem.setSelectable(False)
        self.model().appendRow(firstItem)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    def handleItemPressed(self, index):
        item = self.model().itemFromIndex(index)
        if item.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        else:
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)

    def checkedItems(self):
        l = []
        for i in range(self.model().rowCount()):
            it = self.model().item(i)
            if it.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                l.append(it.text())
        return l

    def hidePopup(self):
        self.closedPopup.emit()
        super(CheckableComboBox, self).hidePopup()
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: self.setCurrentIndex(0))

class Dialog_01(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "Title"  
        self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height = 100, 100, 800, 500
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.flayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(central_widget)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)
        self.years()
        self.location()
        self.MaxYears()

    def years(self):
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Years')

        years = ["2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022"]
        self.comboBoxv = CheckableComboBox()
        for i, area in enumerate(years):
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(area)
            item.setCheckable(True)
            item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.comboBoxv.model().appendRow(item)
        self.flayout.addRow(label, self.comboBoxv)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_closedPopup(self):
        print(len(self.comboBoxv.checkedItems()))

    def location(self):  
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Location')
        combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        for i in range(1,15):
            combobox.addItem("LOCATION %i" % i)
        self.flayout.addRow(label, combobox)

    def MaxYears(self):
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Maximum Years')
        combobox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        for i in range(1, 10):
            combobox.addItem(str(i))
        self.flayout.addRow(label, combobox)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if App is None:
        App = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Dialog_01()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())
```

Comment: here, I see all widgets placed on the layout using central widget have the same size, I was wondering how can I resize each widget to customize?